# How to deploy Kubeflow Components with cloud build?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am using [Containerized Python components](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/author-a-pipeline/components/#2-containerized-python-components) to create the components in my pipeline which works well but I cannot deploy them using Google Cloud Platform Cloud Build.

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'dcgp', '-f', 'cloudbuild/DockerfileDeploy', '.', '--network=cloudbuild']
    id: 'dcgp-build'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ 'run', '--network=cloudbuild', '-v', '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock',
    'dcgp', 'kfp', 'component', 'build', 'stages/simple', '--no-push-image' ]
    id: 'stages-build'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ 'push', 'europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/stages/simple:latest' ]
    waitFor: ['stages-build']
    id: 'stages-deploy'
```

It fails when I try to push in the final step with

`An image does not exist locally with the tag: europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/stages/simple`

I thought because I had mounted the docker daemon in my container in the second stage that it would function like building a pushing any other image like described in [these google docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers).

I want to know if there is a simpler and easier way to deploy kubeflow components using Cloud Build and building my images using the [kubeflow CLI](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/cli/).